# Secure channel with postMessage through IFRAME

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, encryption, postmessage

We have an application outlined below. The UI is provided from a safe domain https://aaa.com, and hosts script from the same domain.

It loads client site https://client.com to an IFRAME. This site can't be trusted and might contain malicious XSS as it's code quality might be generally lower than our application.

The site loads another trusted script from our second domain https://bbb.com. This script could also originate from https://aaa.com if necessary. Both aaa and bbb scripts call REST API from aaa.com, and need security token for that. Security token is obtained by login to UI from the top window on domain aaa.

We need to establish a secure channel in order to pass the security token from the private closure in browser window (scriptA.js) to the private closure in our script in IFRAME (scriptB.js)

As client site is a different domain, we need to use postMessage API for communication of the scripts. Ideally we would like to pass trusted message like "Hey, I am scriptB, send me the token encrypted with this key (assymetric encryption public key generated for that single event), and let scriptA to send encrypted key that malicious XSS can't read".

However the malicious XSS might also fake being scriptB as it sits on the same domain, and send such message earlier with its own key and listen the token from response.

The question is how we could ensure that the request message can be verified in scriptA that it is sent from script loaded from https://bbb.com, and not from XSS loaded from client.com or other domain, or what other ways of secure communication could be used to securely pass token from scriptA to scriptB.

Any suggestions?

[image: Scheme]

Answer (score 1):

Just to let potential visitors know. We didn't come up with a solution to this exact problem, because any means of securing such communication include CORS, which is only usable when you use cookies for authorization. If the communication doesn't involve cookies, attacker server can be used as a forward proxy to bypass any CORS measures included.

Unless the postMessage would include URL of the script (not the hosting window), there seems to be no way to secure such communication and prevent XSS from mimic the target script.

The way we solved it in the end was based on the following assumption:

- Even if the token was secured, the malicious XSS can still emit keyboard and mouse events and this way manipulate with the content the way user could in that given view.

For this reason, we have chosen to wrap the previous more general token as a claim to another token, which is generated by server API called from the parent window context by scriptA (which is secured), and restricts the possible user actions only to ones that can be done by the user actions. This token is the validated on the server which scriptB calls.

This results in a fact that even if XSS would steal the token from the message, it couldn't do more than it could simulating the user actions by faking keyboard and mouse events. In addition to that the token is time limited, so even if XSS steals the token, the attacker cannot preserve it in order to manipulate the same data externally later.

In the end a security bug at client side only compromises his own single page, and not the whole infrastructure.